# Not able to use debug view hierachy

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, xcode7.3

I am currently trying my best to debug my application in Objective-C with the newest version of Xcode7.3
I really need to use Debug View Hierarchy but I am getting an error :

> Assertion failure in -[UITextView _firstBaselineOffsetFromTop],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/UITextView.m:1683

If someone knows how to resolve this ! Thx

Comment: Similar question with Swift and Objective-C workarounds [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37068231/3681880).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug from Apple. There is a radar issue open : https://openradar.appspot.com/25311044

Answer (score 2):

A workaround to resolve this issue. Strictly in debug mode.

```
@interface UITextView(MYTextView)
@end

@implementation UITextView (MYTextView)
- (void)_firstBaselineOffsetFromTop {}
- (void)_baselineOffsetFromBottom {}

@end
```

For swift

```
extension UITextView {
    func _firstBaselineOffsetFromTop() {}
    func _baselineOffsetFromBottom() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the method

`- (void)_firstBaselineOffsetFromTop
{}`

in a UITextView category