# For iOS develop,the debug view hierarchy didn't work

Tags: ios

when I click the debug view hierarchy in `Xcode`, it shows nothing and the console alert:

> Assertion failure in -[UITextView _firstBaselineOffsetFromTop],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3512.60.12/UITextView.m:1683

what confused me is that all my project just this `viewController` occur it.

It's my first time meeting this, could anyone give me some advice.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068231/assertion-failure-in-uitextview-firstbaselineoffsetfromtop Did you try with Xcode 8?

Comment: No，just Xcode 7.2 I had solved this problem by adding category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Assertion failure in UITextView _firstBaselineOffsetFromTop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068231/assertion-failure-in-uitextview-firstbaselineoffsetfromtop)

Write below in your project.

For obj-C

```
@interface UITextView(MYTextView)

@end

@implementation UITextView (MYTextView)
- (void)_firstBaselineOffsetFromTop {

}

- (void)_baselineOffsetFromBottom {

}
@end
```

For swift

```
extension UITextView {
    func _firstBaselineOffsetFromTop() {
    }
    func _baselineOffsetFromBottom() {
    }
}
```